# How To return a list or variable from telethon decorator method

Tags: python-3.x, api, telegram, python-decorators, telethon

i want to take a list out of a **Telethon** NewMessage event handler method , which that it seems a decorator method and use that list somewhere on global scope . How can i do that? (i converted the latest post of a channel to a List of strings and gonna use the list somewhere out of the method)
my Code:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage("Tst"))
async def First_Channel_Handler(event):
    channelPost = str(event.raw_text).lower()
    listedcnlpst = channelPost.split() # How Should i Use the listedcnlpst out of the method?
    # Can not Return it and Call the Method in global !
print(listedcnlpst) # Can not even print it out here , Gives Erorr!
```

Comment: If you could `return` it, where would it go? Who would use it, and how? This might be a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why can't you just use `listedcnlpst` inside the handler?

Comment: i'm going to Search the Listed post For special Words  and send the words to my gmail via Gmail API and Modules automatically .

Comment: or Can you at least Give me another Code that Takes the New Post of a Channel? and be Easier to take some Data(like list of strings) from and the data be Usable in the global, sorry if i'm No0b.

Comment: `client.get_messages` can be used to fetch or search previous history, while `events.NewMessage` is a "live feed". You can either use the former without the need of events, or the latter probably with the use of more `asyncio` tasks.